# Invoke URL Error 502 from browser in AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying my serverless compute in aws. I have created and deployed a simple application that return a string as follows

```
public string FunctionHandler()
{
   return "input will be in UPPER case :-> ";
}
```

This got deployed from visual studio-aws plugin and I am able to invoke it correctly from visual studio test screen. Further, I configured an API gateway that is 'open' end-point. When I call that URL from browser it give internal server error and status 502. Details get response from Aws test windows is below

```
Execution log for request test-request
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /testAnasfn
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {}
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: 
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:126893027727:function:testAnasfn/invocations
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=test-request, Authorization=*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************7d591a, X-Amz-Date=20171112T114400Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=vjvpcua830, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:126893027727:vjvpcua830/null/GET/testAnasfn, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_vjvpcua830, X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoDYXdzEBQaDMyv494SIfdIl+qxLSK5AygkNULmfxDTCe8srTRObtfH8Gycwy22pkJzTD/fp+peUByQbXRD1MTeFFQHn6t+hulEBbAdESX0goX9/fytIFksJnMlT+/E+OlfIx17YwqqRIw+0dieUgDCl80J12UYR2CNPQFdc3yU5F60QXf4EjpgXOVTClSSSbqeXKZQ8M9BgzD3YsRbXnpVsRlpELJaV7i9R1rSeuI6ix66NPgpd+cp4578Fhpuol3xlueqk0JnlJZ9NtwH0N8vLbH3R2ZP0yPY8a9Pp19qHkVz9C2DzNXenChwxEb9seVZR7D92FIg8rBcQQkzDlbDa2D2lVMeSImhdlsvF/ttlpgWnpfeB [TRUNCATED]
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/testAnasfn","path":"/testAnasfn","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"path":"/testAnasfn","accountId":"126893027727","resourceId":"v0n0zx","stage":"test-invoke-stage","requestId":"test-invoke-request","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"accountId":"126893027727","cognitoIdentityId":null,"caller":"126893027727","apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","sourceIp":"test-invoke-source-ip","accessKey":"ASIAJNBVXURNV3ICQ2YA","cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:iam::126893027727:root","userAgent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_144)","user":"126893027727"},"resourcePath":"/testAnasfn","httpMethod":"GET","apiId":"vjvpcua830"},"body":null,"isBase64Encoded":false}
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Sending request to https://lambda.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:126893027727:function:testAnasfn/invocations
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Received response. Integration latency: 19 ms
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "input will be in UPPER case :-> "
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=c65a341b-c79e-11e7-8ef4-17eaf422a581, Content-Length=34, Date=Sun, 12 Nov 2017 11:44:00 GMT, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5a083400-b65593a405f54027ad55da5c;sampled=0, Content-Type=application/json}
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Sun Nov 12 11:44:00 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 502
```

I tried to call it from jQuery Ajax but failed status received.

I checked Use Lambda Proxy integration for using it from Proxy!

**UPDATE 1**

When I unchecked *Use Lambda Proxy* integration on *Integration Request* in API gateway and test application I get corrected response with status 200.

```
Execution log for request test-request
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /testAnas1
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {}
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: 
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:126893027727:function:testAnas1/invocations
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=test-request, Authorization=***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************bd4940, X-Amz-Date=20171112T194419Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=ntn0u9y8gk, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:126893027727:ntn0u9y8gk/null/GET/testAnas1, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_ntn0u9y8gk, X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoDYXdzEBwaDKFa4kx/RGE/fe8dqyK5A7wMpA/qRGHmUARstMAvEJvFe3rvi32sR0faLB+IUTb8wOMeehIgNJ4O/QD+5CuM26+q6xnCN5Ov5qJvENp63KiqmNuhpub5hoDutE1zAahQsLoKzx5Muqy+/tzJ9yQCXaA1eHklH0XNNG9BZjgz1JANoPNfMGSvY8KBEqARH6fCEdOuSz0/KJeALd9xYbHATO0ml5ucXJLqVEZFPuwbwrfbFHINGXkjgpJCLwc5x4YoY+9bWzkuWc+akkMIeyRDmKvii88Qa3MCnbJz9wUqzG/bjh8QpVdg4M/dFhG3lor0s1tdT6r4w47MeUaJgqxAQXO+7eGTA2PfPWdsoB1JGl2qriDXwamgSQJEkpHCgGaZzk88lyEgabUI [TRUNCATED]
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Sun Nov 12 19:44:19 UTC 2017 : Sending request to https://lambda.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:126893027727:function:testAnas1/invocations
Sun Nov 12 19:44:20 UTC 2017 : Received response. Integration latency: 80 ms
Sun Nov 12 19:44:20 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "I am Ahmad Anas"
Sun Nov 12 19:44:20 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=e0201f5e-c7e1-11e7-8754-61ed0803d92c, Content-Length=17, Date=Sun, 12 Nov 2017 19:44:20 GMT, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5a08a493-f27ad9f6b7e304c7ef148949;sampled=0, Content-Type=application/json}
Sun Nov 12 19:44:20 UTC 2017 : Method response body after transformations: "I am Ahmad Anas"
Sun Nov 12 19:44:20 UTC 2017 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=sampled=0;root=1-5a08a493-f27ad9f6b7e304c7ef148949, Content-Type=application/json}
Sun Nov 12 19:44:20 UTC 2017 : Successfully completed execution
Sun Nov 12 19:44:20 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 200
```

But my problem persist and when I call *Invoke URL* status code 502 is returned. Note that I have created ProductionTest1 stage.

**ANSWER**

I am certainly not allowed for now to answer my own question but I think it's OK to answer [Myself] as update. **Short Answer** : Frame your own response in C# then deploy on lambda as below in code.

```
public APIGatewayProxyResponse FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
        //context.Logger.LogLine("This is useful for debugging!"); 
        return new APIGatewayProxyResponse()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Body = "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        };
}
```

Now come to a bit detail. To work with AWS Lambda you can use HTTP Proxy Integration with a Proxy Resource (In case)

*The HTTP proxy integration, designated by HTTP_PROXY in the API Gateway REST API, is for integrating a method request with a backend HTTP endpoint. **With this integration type, API Gateway simply passes the entire request and response between the frontend and the backend,** subject to certain restrictions and limitations.* [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html)

So, as a possible solution you can create a simple object of your own or use one provided by AWS - APIGatewayProxyResponse. [More](https://www.benprogblog.com/post/using-serverless-writing-lambda-functions-in-c-sharp/) Use NuGet for this `Install-Package Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents -Version 1.1.0`

I hope this will resolve the issue and brief on response object trick!

Comment: Do any of these help? https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Execution+failed+due+to+configuration+error%3A+Malformed+Lambda+proxy+response

Comment: @mjwills certainly not very help for now

Comment: @Anas read the top answer in the linked question.  It appears to exactly explain what your problem is.  Lambda Proxy Integration requires a specific response format from Lambda.